# How align an appended image in Google Docs using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, google-docs

This script gets a value from an html element and appends it into a gdocs as a textappendText() and a QR code codeappendInlineImage() incrementally. It does the job so far.

Now I've been trying to align the text and the image in the destination gDocs automatically, but I can't get the syntax right.

I've included an image of my current results and expected results.
[image: example image]

This is my script so far.

```
function createQRCodeSingleItem(fieldData) {
var doc = DocumentApp.openById('1NRSSD_gdfgdfgergdfgdfgdf');
var body = doc.getBody();
var qrCode = fieldData.productId.toString();

 //Logger.log(qrCode)

var url = "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=" + qrCode
var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url); // Get the image of QR code
body.getChild(0).asParagraph().appendText(qrCode);// QR Code referencence number
body.getChild(0).asParagraph().appendInlineImage(resp.getBlob());// OR code
var msg = 'Item INCLUIDO com sucesso!'
    Logger.log(msg);
      return msg;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this example doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1wTKh4Exk7VE9ZYlDtdp7XDzhytCwJrZIMd8d6cJraJQ/edit?usp=sharing).

You can align the image using the [`addPositionedImage()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/positioned-image) for the paragraph in question.

```js
 function createQRCodeSingleItem() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var qrCode = '990';  // sample qrCode

  var url = "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=" + qrCode
  var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url); // Get the image of QR code
  // Get or create your desired paragraph
  var paragraph = body.appendParagraph(qrCode).setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
  // add positioned image with offsets... Figure out your optimal offset points values
  paragraph.addPositionedImage(resp.getBlob()).setTopOffset(-50).setLeftOffset(75);
}
```

Here is the [Apps Script](https://script.google.com/d/1kbRhoVdk0NgC3JKjTAJ2WGt8cPmBaCrLtzcrMW8PHHNAdkTdUQ2fBf2h/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hi, your recommendation works as far as the first layout. But as I add additional values to the list it will not append to the same line. insted it just overlaps the first image paragraph.addPositionedImage(resp.getBlob()).setTopOffset(-50).setLeftOffset(20); Do I need to setup some kind of template?

Comment: The offsets work from the paragraph they are bound to. So you should create a new paragraph for each 4 images or so. Otherwise they will be all offseting from the same start point.

[`setLeftOffset()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/positioned-image#setleftoffsetoffset)

[`setTopOffset()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/positioned-image#settopoffsetoffset)

Comment: I understand the logic but my coding knowledge is scares. I've tried some variations including this body.getChild(0).asParagraph().appendText(qrCode); but I get no where. I'm looking at the documentation page to see if I can implement your suggestion.